# KeyValue pair is being added to web.config file although file property is defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, web-config

```
 Configuration config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
  config.SectionGroups.Add("testing", new ConfigurationSectionGroup());         
  ConfigurationSectionGroup testing = config.SectionGroups["testing"];
  testing.Sections.Add("subsec", new AppSettingsSection() {File="tst.config" });
  KeyValueConfigurationCollection settings = ((AppSettingsSection)testing.Sections["subsec"]).Settings;

  settings.Add("tst", "ok");
config.Save();
```

the result is:

```
    <sectionGroup name="testing" type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionGroup, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" >
      <section name="subsec" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </sectionGroup>

  <testing>
    <subsec file="tst.config">
      <add key="tst" value="ok" /> //this should not be here but must be added to the tst.config file
    </subsec>
  </testing>
```

Why it is not adding the settings to the file?

Comment: Not 100% sure I understand this one, what is missing from the result?

Comment: @FionaTaylorGorringe `<add key="tst" value="ok" />` should be added to the tst.config file but as you see in the results its in the web.config file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to set the config source programmatically (instead of `File`) like so:

```
ConfigurationSection subsec = config.GetSection("testing/subsec");
subsec.SectionInformation.ConfigSource = "tst.config";
```

Comment: If I define `configSource` instead of `file` it adds and reads from the config source (everything is ok) the problem is that as the section is created programmatically, I don't have the option to define a configSource. (or do I?)

Comment: I see, have added another option (not tested).

Comment: I just modified your code to exactly match my example in the question